# How to chain laravel model query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I was extending laravel model scope query using :

```
public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
   return new FooBuilder($query);
}

public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
   return new BarBuilder($query);
}

class FooBuilder extends Builder
{
  public function joinBar()
  {
    return $this->leftJoin('bar', 'bar.id', '=', 'foo.id');
  }
}

class BarBuilder extends Builder
{
   public function whereActive()
   {
     return $this->where('is_active', true);
   }
}
```

Is it possible to chain laravel model query like this?

```
Foo::query()->joinBar()->Bar::query()->whereActive()->get()
```

Basically, I want to call a method in `BarBuilder` from `FooBuilder`, i dont want to add duplicate same method inside `FooBuilder`.

Comment: You mean you want to fetch `Users::where()->get()` returns `Users` with `Orders` while `Orders` with `OrderStatus` like structure?

Comment: i already update my question @roa

Answer (score 2):

You might be overcomplicating this TBH. Take a look at Scopes:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes.

You should simply be able to define the following on `Foo.php` (Model):

```php
public function scopeJoinBar($query){
  return $query->leftJoin('bar', 'bar.id', '=', 'foo.id');
}

public function scopeBarIsActive($query){
  return $query->where('bar.is_active', true);
}
```

Then you simply call these scopes:

```php
$foos = Foo::joinBar()->barIsActive()->get();
```

Comment: thanks, but what if i want to get it like this `$bar = Bar::barIsActive()->get` ? since the `barIsActive` was inside `Foo.php` , how do i access `scopeBarIsActive`  from `Bar.php`?

Comment: You wouldn't really; you'd simply do `Bar::where('is_active', true)->get();`. Or, look at Global Scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes. You'd define it like in the documentation, and it would be available to all Eloquent models. Or you'd redefine it on `Bar.php`, but that would be if the other 2 options didn't work, since that would be duplication of code :)

Comment: yeah, the purpose i want to chain it was to avoid code duplication :) . I already take a look at laravel global scope but that seems not suit to my use case.

Comment: *"[...] seems not suit to my use case"* - Can you expand on that? Global scopes are designed to be usable on specific models to avoid code duplication... Is that not your exact use case?

Comment: laravel global scope requires to create a new class and apply it in the model boot method, i wonder if i have more than 10 global scope, it would be a pain to handle it, i would prefer something that a la carte that we can add in whenever we want instead of all combine together in the boot method

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that's a valid point. Keep in mind though that you don't necessarily _need_ to have a scope for everything. In practice, scopes should be used for shared query constraints, or complex where's, or things that could be updated to avoid having to update in multiple places. In most of my projects, I don't have many scopes (probably less than 10), so again, possibly overthinking this :) But anyway, if you do come up with something, feel free to post a self-answer!